# "Bohnerze" pisolitic ore in Switzerland

Tags: limestone, ore, iron, mesozoic

I am going hunting for iron ore in Switzerland and the plan is to visit some old abandoned mines in the Jura mountains. I am not quite sure exactly what I am looking for though, in the past I have found a lot of magnetite in other countries, but I do not think that is present here.

In a report by the USGS I found the following passage:

> Jura Mountains -- In the Jura Mountains of western Switzerland are
> found the so-called "Bohnerze" -- pisolitic ores derived from Mesozoic
> iron-bearing limestones by superficial disintegration during the
> Eocene epoch. They are low-grade, slightly titaniferous ores which
> contain 42 per cent of iron after washing.

What does this kind of "Bohnerze" ore actually look like, and how would I best find it? Will the ore be magnetic?

Comment: https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohnerz

Answer (score 3):

[Bohnerz](https://www.mindat.org/min-708.html) is the German word for "bean ore". Another translation is "[nuggets](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/238682786_Origin_of_Iron_Ore_Nuggets_Bohnerze_through_Weathering_of_Basalt_as_Documented_by_Pebbles_from_the_Herbstlabyrinth_Breitscheid-Germany)".

You might like to try the [Wangen Valley in Switzerland](https://www.myswitzerland.com/en-ch/experiences/pisolitic-iron-ore-in-the-wangen-valley/).

Pisolitic iron deposits consist of small pebbles that are roughly pea shaped and similar in size to peas. The individual pebbles formed as concretions. The picture below shows [Bean ore from a gravel plant near Genkingen/Swabian Alb](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohnerz).

[image]